# Update ListView after changing database

Tags: java, android, listview, cursor

I'm using cursor to show database in ListView and updating it this way

```
getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
```

The problem is that it doesn't work properly. When the changing method is called from the same class and doesn't start any new intents, ListView updates just fine, thought otherwise nothing changes.

For example this has no effect

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ItemAdd.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
        }
    });
```

Do you have any suggestions why does it happend? Any fixes?

---

The problem appears to be in running update before it even happened. Now I'm using

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)          {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 100) {
        getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your adapter for ListView extend of CursorAdapter. 
Then you can use

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```